# Перевод приложения на python pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, интернационализация

Помогите разобраться  с QTranlator, хочу перевести приложение, однако не знаю как. Если надо, то поправлю вопрос и выложу код приложения, которое надо перевести.

Comment: Проверьте некоторые посты по данной тематике. Если после изучения у вас что-то не получится, приведете ваш код и покажите попытки того что вы пытались сделать.